# Conversion a string to float

Tags: c#

I have a problem with how to convert a string to a float.
Here is my code on C#, please try to help me.

```
string Valeur = "16.2 dB";
Console.WriteLine(Valeur);
float seuil = 6;
string Valeur_optimisé = Valeur.Substring(0, Valeur.Length - 3);//Pour supprimer ( dB)
Console.WriteLine(Valeur_optimisé);
float var1 = (Convert.ToSingle(Valeur_optimisé));//J'ai une exception sur cette ligne
//Console.WriteLine(var1);
if (var1 < seuil)
{
Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What is your _problem_ exactly? What is the exception message as English? On which line? And what is your `CurrentCulture`? Can you please clarify your question? It is a little bit unclear.

Comment: it means , there is an error on conversion in this line

Comment: The problem is on this line: 
float var1 = (Convert.ToSingle(Valeur_optimisé));
It seems like the conversion doesn't work

Comment: Please, explain the **problem**.

Comment: i want to campare var 1 and seuil. And as u saw it , "seuil" is a float and "valeur" is a string , i delated characters ( dB) from "valeur" and when i wanted to campre between "var1" and "seuil", they say there is an error.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this using `TryParse`

```
float var1;
Single.TryParse(Valeur_optimisé, out var1);
```

Comment: when i use : 
float var1;
Single.TryParse(Valeur_optimisé, out var1);

Var=0 and we know that this value is !=0

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
float.Parse(Valeur_optimisé, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Comment: IMO - Float.Parse would throw exception if the passed string is not a float.

Comment: @Ashutosh Vyas, you're right. i just gave another way to do the conversion.